# "The URL could not be validated", facebook api error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a `facebook api` for the first time. I am using `PHP Open Graph SDK`. I searched from internet and found some tutorials, so I followed these steps and make a folder `fb-test` and in folder i create these files `login.php` and `fb-callback.php` and write my `app_id` and `app_secret` in these files.

When I open mysite with this url:

> www.mysite.com/fb-test/login.php

and my login page open with facebook login button. When I click on this button, the facebook page open and give me this error:

[image]

Then I searched about it and I go to settings tab and write my site url like that:

[image]

But it still gives me the same above error. So I searched again and I found that go to Webhooks tab and write my verify toke and callback file link Like:

[image]

So again I searched a lot but nothing found.

So please help me out to solve this problem. Hope you understand my question.

Comment: Is SSL is enabled on your domain ?

Comment: So your problem is related to login? Then why are you filling out webhook/subscription settings? Those are two completely different things. // Go check the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs setting. The value of the redirect_uri parameter as it appears in your login dialog URL, must be entered in there.

Comment: No ... SSL is not open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove values from `web hooks`.

Then go to settings and select `advanced` tab like

[image]

and then scroll down to `client OAuth settings` and then enter the fb-callback file in url like

[image]

That's it.

Comment: Thanx alot bro ... you saved my day